# Windows server behind NAT with multiple websites in hyper-v VM's

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016, windows-home-server

Excuse me if the title is a bit misleading.  I have a server ( Dell r710 , 64GB RAM, with Windows Server 2016).

I have a business developing websites but want to expand into having my own server/data center to reduce expense of hosting and for the satisfaction of obtaining more knowledge. I am the only person running the business so I have to be the network admin guy along with being a developer.

I have a NAT router/modem and multiple VM's on my server. My server has 4 Ethernet ports, I have two connected from the server to the router.

I Just cant wrap my head around how to correctly run the server and network traffic.  Do I create a virtual machine with nginx and port forward the routers public IP to the ip of my nginx server within the VM and then have nginx direct the user to a certain VM?

How do you have your office/home server set up and what method do you use to effectively direct users to the multiple sites running on your server ?

Also, could I setup two name servers within two separate VM's and handle DNS resolution that way ? Please help

My goal is simply to host multiple websites on one windows server within hyper-v VM's.

Please help me out And also work with me in anyway possible by asking questions that you may have. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hosting customers' sites in your home is not on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have 2 NIC's on the host connected to the router? What are you using the 2 NIC's for?

1. You can port forward all HTTP traffic from your router to a single VM and use host headers for each website to differentiate between them. This is just one way of doing it. If you want to port forward HTTP traffic to more than one VM then you'll need to use some kind of proxy VM to do that.
2. Could you run your own DNS servers for your public domain names? Yes you could, but don't. A very many Registrars provide DNS hosting at no cost when you register a domain so let them host the DNS zones for your domains. The registrar has specific expertise in hosting and managing DNS that you don't (no offense) so let them handle the DNS while you focus on your core competency and money making activities.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have two connected because hyper-v suggested using one port for a virtual machine to give internet access to all my VMs and then the other port to remote into the server.

Comment: hank you for the reply. I have two connected because hyper-v suggested using one port for a virtual machine to give internet access to all my VMs and then the other port to remote into the server. About the DNS, my registrar does not offer the service of hosting DNS zones. Do you know if cloud flare  host DNS zones or would you recommend something like dyn.org ?

Comment: I took your advice and now have my site up and running on my home server. Thanks so so much